# The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', version '2.2.0' was not found

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

`Dotnet --version` says 2.2.402

`dotnet --info` says

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.402
 Commit:    c7f2f96116

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     centos
 OS Version:  7
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         centos.7-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.8
  Commit:  b9aa1abc51

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I'm trying to publish my app on linux server which is working quite fine on server till my last try to update the application on server using the below command.

`dotnet publish -c release -o ${API_PUBLISH_DIR}`

the build process is throwing the following error

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
>     The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', version '2.2.0' was not found.
>       - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>           /usr/share/dotnet/
>       - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
>           https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
>       - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
>           https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

more error details is.

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation/2.2.0/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.targets(64,5): error MSB3073: The command ""/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet" exec --runtimeconfig "/home/vng-dev/vng-web/vast-webapplication/vast_webapplication/WebAPI/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/WebAPI.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "/home/vng-dev/vng-web/vast-webapplication/vast_webapplication/WebAPI/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/WebAPI.deps.json" "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation/2.2.0/build/netstandard2.0/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.dll" @"obj/Release/netcoreapp2.2/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"" exited with code 150. [/home/vng-dev/vng-web/vast-webapplication/vast_webapplication/WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj]

I didn't mentioned the version in .csproj file for AspNetCore.All and it's like this

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All"  />`

also tried replacing `AspNetCore.All` with `AspNetCore.App` like below

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"  />`

this also doesn't help

I also tried with installing AspNetCore.MVC.Razor.ViewCompilation package but it doesn't help

**EDIT:**

1. Also tried updating the versions of both Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and Microsoft.AspNetCore.All one at a time.
2. tried compiling the app with versions attribute and without versions attribute.
3. Tried updating all the project (.csproj) files in the solution.

Comment: Have you ever try installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`

Comment: @Anduin yeah tried that also and it still throw an error during publish. It was all working fine just before this publish try.

Comment: Did you update your SDK recently? There's been an issue with the latest update. See https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3886 and related issues. I would report it there too.

Comment: yes just recently updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it turns out issue in the build command

I'm using this command -> `dotnet publish -c release -o ${API_PUBLISH_DIR}`

changed this and add the platform on which I'm building it

`dotnet publish -c release -r linux-x64 -o  ${API_PUBLISH_DIR}`

The recent automatic updates to .net core messes up something and couldn't figure out where are the version dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your project has a reference of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All similar to what given below. But you have installed dotnet core 2.2.x, after dotnet core 2.0  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` is being removed. Microsoft.NETCore.App is much lighter version similar to that package.

I would suggest installing dotnet core 2.0. In that case, you dont need to change your project.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All"/>
```

Comment: can't move back to 2.0. My solution is deployed fine until the last publish attempt. In fact the same code is currently working on stage environment with the same dontnet --info

Comment: you can try removing `Version`

Answer (score 0):

- Add dotnet core 2.0 version in your Project

> < PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6"/>

- Also Add In property group

> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>   <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```